# Separating value in awk

Tags: awk, sed

I am stuck with approach need to seperate value before `/` and after `/`
Here is file content:

```
Min/Max Inference Time : 70 ms / 290 ms
 Average Inference Time : 90 ms
```

Expected Output:

```
Min : 70
Max : 290
```

Here what I have tried:

```
cat scores.csv | awk '/\//' | sed 's/ms//g'| awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"}{print $2}'
```

But I dont how to seperate the value  before `/` and after `/` for above expected output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try awk with multiple delimiters

```
$ echo "Min/Max Inference Time : 70 ms / 290 ms" | \
awk -F"[/ ]+" ' { print $1, ":", $(NF-3); print $2,":",$(NF-1) } '
Min : 70
Max : 290
$
```

***EDIT1:*** FS should not change

```
$ echo "Min/Max Inference Time : 70 ms / 290 ms" | awk -F: -v OFS=":" ' {  split($1,a,"[ /]+"); split($2,b,"ms|/"); print a[1],b[1]; print a[2],b[3] } '
Min: 70
Max: 290
$
```

***EDIT2:***

```
$ awk -F: -v OFS=":" ' { if(/\//) {  split($1,a,"[ /]+"); split($2,b,"ms|/"); print a[1],b[1]; print a[2],b[3] } else { print } }' scores.csv
Min: 70
Max: 290
 Average Inference Time : 90 ms
$
```

with Perl,

```
$ perl -lne  ' /(.+?)\/(.+?)\s+.+?(\d+).+?(\d+)/ ? print $1,": ",$3,"\n",$2,": ",$4 : print ' scores.csv
Min: 70
Max: 290
 Average Inference Time : 90 ms
$
```

Comment: I do not want to change the field seperator `:` as other scores are depending

Comment: you mean.. the output separator?.. can you additional samples?

Comment: No input FS to remain `:`

Comment: I added additional sample

Comment: @Arya.. can you check the EDIT1?

Comment: Not coming with expected output, see the additional samples above in the my post

Comment: @Arya.. I have added Perl solution as well.. both the results are matching with Wiktors

Answer (score 1):

You may use a single `sed` command:

```
sed -E 's,.*\b([0-9]+[[:blank:]]*ms)[[:blank:]]*/[[:blank:]]*([0-9]+[[:blank:]]*ms).*,Min : \1\nMax : \2,'   scores.csv  >  new_scores.csv
```

See the [online sed demo](https://ideone.com/h0XvtH)

**Pattern details**

- `.*\b` - any 0+ chars, as many as possible, up to the word boundary followed with the subsequent patterns

  - `([0-9]+[[:blank:]]*ms)` - Group 1: 1 or more digits, 0+ whitespaces, `ms` substring
  - `[[:blank:]]*/[[:blank:]]*` - a `/` enclosed with 0 or more whitespaces
  - `([0-9]+[[:blank:]]*ms)` - Group 2: 1 or more digits, 0+ whitespaces, `ms` substring
  - `.*` - the rest of the line.

The replacement pattern is `Min : \1\nMax : \2`, where `\1` refers to the text captured with Group 1 and `\2` refers to the text captured with Group 2.

Answer (score 1):

the first thing you could split with space and slash. And look at each element:

```
awk -F'[/ ]' '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) print i ": " $i}' scores.csv
1: Min
2: Max
3: Inference
4: Time
5: :
6: 70
7: ms
8:
9:
10: 290
11: ms
```

after that you take the right elements:

```
awk -F'[/ ]' '{ print "Min : " $6; print "Max : " $10 }' scores.csv
Min : 70
Max : 290
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following. Simply setting proper `FS`(field separators) for each lines and then printing them(NO manipulation of data etc)

```
awk -F"Inference Time : |/| ms" -v OFS=" : " 'FNR==1{$1=$1;print $1,$3 ORS $2,$5}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code now.

```
awk -F"Inference Time : |/| ms" -v OFS=" : " '     ##Setting field separator as string Inference Time :  OR / OR ms for all lines and setting OFS as space colon space here.
FNR==1{                                            ##Checking condition if line is 1st line then do following.
  $1=$1                                            ##Re-setting $1=$1 to reflect value of OFS here.
  print $1,$3 ORS $2,$5                            ##Printing values of $1,$3 then ORS with $2,$5 here as per OP ask.
}                                                  ##Closing BLOCK for FNR==1 condition here.
'  Input_file                                      ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Min : 70
Max  :  290
```

Comment: @Arya, could you please check this answer and let me know if this helps, added proper explanation too here.